# Getting error when creating connection to MySQL server driver

Tags: mysql, sql-server, jdbc-odbc

I installed MySQL server and I also test this server by creating user data base userlist table and also check that it is working fine on command line as I previously done. But This time getting error when try to create a user.

[image]

I already used this but actauly I format my system and creating connection again. But this time getting error.

Comment: Your question text says MySQL but the error message looks like Microsoft SQL Server and you've tagged both DBMS products.  Which is it?  If you want to connect to MySQL, you need to specify a different ODBC driver.

Comment: @ Dan Guzman - SQL Server MVP, I am creating new User DSN to connect it with my java program by the help of username and password. In past time I use MS Office Driver to use as database for java application. But Now i want to use MySql server so that I can work on persistent storage.